# List/matrix of coefficients equation (system of equations)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I try to extract coefficient from equations (system of equations) into list (matrix). I have tried `CoefficientList[poly, {var1, var2, ...}]` but without success.

This simple example should explain my problem:

```
Eq1 = a D[U[x1, x2], {x1, 2}] + b D[V[x1, x2], {x2, 2}]
```

[image: reproduce problem]

Any advice?

**Edit:**

Daniel's Lichtblau solution is very clear (thanks you), but what if the equation that looks like this?

```
Eq1 = a D[U[x1, x2], {x1, 2}] + b D[V[x1, x2], {x2, 2}] + c W[x1, x2]
```

A simple example can be resolved as follows:

[image: additional question]

Is there any more elegant solution? (particularly for more complex expressions)

Ps I can't understand why, but this solution gives me the correct result.

[image: reproduce problem]

Comment: What if you state `CoefficientList[Eq1, {V^(0,2)[x1,x2], U^(2,0)[x1, x2]}]`?

Comment: How about `CoefficientList[
 a D[U[x1, x2], {x1, 2}] + b D[V[x1, x2], {x2, 2}], { 
  D[U[x1, x2], {x1, 2}], D[V[x1, x2], {x2, 2}]}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly the partial derivatives are represented with `Derivative`, so the pattern needs to match that. Also, I don't think you want to use `CoefficientList` as that would accept terms where both your expressions appear. All in all, the following should work:

```
In[7]:= (Coefficient[Eq1, #] &) /@ {Derivative[2, 0][U][x1, x2], Derivative[0, 2][V][x1, x2]}
Out[7]= {a, b}
```

Here `(Coefficient[Eq1, #] &)` is an anonymous function that finds the coefficient of the argument, and `/@` maps it to the list on the right.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

CoefficientArrays is often useful for extracting coefficients to linear systems in some set of variables. In this case we first need to get the list of variables.

```
dvars = Cases[Eq1, Derivative[__][_][__], -1];
```

CoefficientArrays returns a result of the form {constants, coefficients}. it uses sparse arrays so I'll convert to explicit lists with Normal.

```
Normal[CoefficientArrays[Eq1, dvars]]
```

Out[672]= {0, {b, a}}

Daniel Lichtblau
Wolfram Research

Comment: Excellent. Thanks you. I've updated the question. I would be very grateful if you could look at it.